# Tracking Motion Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

How can I know when the phone is tilted in the opposite direction to change the sprites orientation?

This is the code reading the phones accelerometer and telling the sprite where to move and how fast

```
- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {

accelerometerData = _motionManager.accelerometerData;
CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;

CGFloat newXPosition = MainSprite.position.x + acceleration.y * 1000 * delta;
newXPosition = clampf(newXPosition, 0, self.contentSize.width);
MainSprite.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, MainSprite.position.y); 

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by opposite direction? also is this in portrait or landscape mode?

Comment: Landscape 
When the screen is tilted to a certain direction the sprite will aim in that direction